# How to sign user space binary with force integrity check (deprecated MSFT cross-signing)

Tags: certificate, code-signing, portable-executable, windows-defender

We used to have a binary running in user space built with VC++ /integritycheck flag which sets IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY flag on executable (see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/cpp/build/reference/integritycheck-require-signature-check?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/255.forced-integrity-signing-of-portable-executable-pe-files.aspx)). We signed it with our old certificate and it run smoothly. Now we were given new certificate and binary is blocked by security check (defender prompt + log in event log).

[image: Audit fail event]

- Yes, we added certificate to our trusted store.
- Yes, we used page hash (/ph) switch while signing.
- New cert running fine if we enable test sign on a platform (through bcdedit)

The major difference seems to be that new certificate is not cross signed by Microsoft. [Cross signing is no longer supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/deprecation-of-software-publisher-certificates-and-commercial-release-certificates) so maybe anyone knows if there's alternative or how to workaround it? Maybe /integritycheck flag for user space code is no longer valid?

Same issue we found at MSFT forum https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/348812/signed-file-fails-to-start-because-of-bad-signatur.html. Still no precise answers how to solve it.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Microsoft updated the documentation on [`/INTEGRITYCHECK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/integritycheck-require-signature-check?view=msvc-170) one month ago. They say that you must use Azure Code Signing. I would be interested in knowing how you solved your problem.